# NSMutableDictionary not getting expected output.

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Its only outputting one set for NSMutableDictionary not both. I want to create an JSON request using NSMutableDictionary (JSONRepresentation).

```
// My code    

NSArray *keysEndpoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID", @"Name", @"EndpointType", nil];
NSArray *objectEndpoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"622", @"Brand", @"0", nil];

NSArray *keysEndpoint1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID", @"Name", @"EndpointType", nil];
NSArray *objectEndpoint1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"595", @"CK-05052011", @"1", nil];

NSMutableArray *keys1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableArray *objects1 =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

[keys1 addObjectsFromArray:keysEndpoint];
[keys1 addObjectsFromArray:keysEndpoint1];

NSLog(@"Key Dic: %@", keys1);

[objects1 addObjectsFromArray:objectEndpoint];
[objects1 addObjectsFromArray:objectEndpoint1];

NSLog(@"Obje Dic: %@", objects1);

NSMutableDictionary *testMut = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects1  forKeys:keys1];

NSLog(@"Test Dic: %@", testMut);
```

Output is am getting is this:

```
 Test Dic: {
    EndpointType = 1;
    ID = 595;
    Name = "CK-05052011";
}
```

Expexted output i want is :

```
Test Dic: {
    EndpointType = 1;
    ID = 595;
    Name = "CK-05052011";
} 
{
    EndpointType = 0;
    ID = 622;
    Name = "Brand";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dictionary, adding the same keys twice will override the first set of keys.  You should have a NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary

```
NSArray *keysEndpoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID", @"Name", @"EndpointType", nil];
NSArray *objectEndpoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"622", @"Brand", @"0", nil];

NSArray *keysEndpoint1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID", @"Name", @"EndpointType", nil];
NSArray *objectEndpoint1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"595", @"CK-05052011", @"1", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *testMut = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objectsEndpoint  forKeys:keysEndpoint];


NSMutableDictionary *testMut1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objectsEndpoint1  forKeys:keysEndpoint1];

NSMutableArray * dictArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:testMut,testMut1,nil];

NSLog(@"Test DictArray: %@", dictArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works grate but problem is, i have more than 20 array  for key point and object endpoint. I can't create 20 NSMutableDictionary. Is there any way to do it programmatically ?

Comment: @AmitVyawahare Where are you getting the key point and object endpoint data from? It is definitely possible to populated this data dynamically. For turning the data to a json object, you can look up examples of SBJson or JSONKit on SO.